# В pytube не могу определить стрим на YouTube при помощи исключения exceptions.LiveStreamError

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, pytube

Добрый день при помощи библиотеки pytube не могу определить стрим на YouTube

```py
from pytube import YouTube
from pytube import exceptions

video = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dx5qFachd3A'
        
try:
   yt = YouTube(video)
   print (yt.title)

except exceptions.LiveStreamError:
    print('exceptions.LiveStreamError')
```

Выдаётся вот такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test2.py", line 7, in <module>
    yt = YouTube(video)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pytube/__main__.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.descramble()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pytube/__main__.py", line 132, in descramble
    apply_descrambler(self.player_config_args, fmt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pytube/extract.py", line 281, in apply_descrambler
    formats = json.loads(stream_data["player_response"])["streamingData"]["formats"]
KeyError: 'formats'
```

Использую python3
pytube устанавливал так: `pip3 install pytube3 --upgrade`

Подскажите пожалуйста в чём моя ошибка? Или как мне при помощи библиотеки pytube определить что по ссылке стрим, а не видео?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Проблема](https://github.com/nficano/pytube/pull/612) не в коде, а в самом pytube3. Решается она фиксом, при наличии установленного GIT:

```
pip3 uninstall -y pytube3
pip3 install "git+https://github.com/tooxo/pytube.git@fix_609"
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Это помогло

Comment: Но вот только не понятно почему не отрабатывает print('exceptions.LiveStreamError')

Comment: Вы же отлавливаете конкретный exception, если он не отрабатывает, значит вызывается исключение другого типа

Comment: В том то и дело, что я проверяю видео, которое является стримом. 
Насколько я понял исключение exceptions.LiveStreamError должно срабатывать если видео является стримом, что в данном случае не срабатывает.

Как так?

Comment: exceptions.LiveStreamError должно срабатывать не если видео является стримом, а если возникают ошибки в ходе чтения информации о нем. Полагаю, что таких ошибок не возникает

Comment: Понятно. А не подскажешь как можно определить является видео стримом или нет?